# Data structure layout - NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I’m looking for the best way to store data like this...

Value 1
  -item 1
  -item 2
  -item 3
  ...
  -item 9
Value 2
  -item 1
  ...
  -item 9
Value 3
etc...

Then I want to pick a subset of the items for a given “value”

Is NSMutableDictionary the way to go for this?  I’m getting a little confused in setting this up.
I’ve been trying this... but its not quite right apparently.  Thanks for the help.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
[dictionary setObject:@"Entry1" forKey:@"1"];
[dictionary setObject:@"1-Entry2" forKey:@"1"];
[dictionary setObject:@"Entry2" forKey:@"2"];
[dictionary setObject:@"Entry3" forKey:@"3"];

NSLog(@"1: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"1"]);
NSLog(@"/n 2: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"1"]);
```

Comment: Don't forget to initiate your dictionary! Use `NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Comment: I was using arc, so I can’t do it that way, right?

Comment: A dictionary can have only one item for each key- does your data have more than one entry per key?

Comment: ARC or not, you must initiate your objects before using them. The only difference with ARC is who's holding onto the object. If you fail to allocate a new object, your pointer is pointing at nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want multiple objects under a single key, you need to use arrays inside the dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item1", @"item2", nil] forKey:@"Key1"];
```

and so on.

Comment: I would say even if order doesn't matter you can still use `NSArray`. Use `NSSet` when you are worried about all values in your collection being unique.

Comment: @nielsbot good point. I added that as an afterthought, thinking of his structure as kind of a multimap, but it really isn't a good idea to recommend using NSSet unless it's necessary.